# Bulk printing\exporting from ArcGIS for Desktop to PDF or JPG for 300 layers using same extent?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, printing, pdf, batch

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.2 for Desktop and I need to print\export individual maps of some 300 point Shape\layers (plant occurrences) to PDF (or JPG). Basemap extent remains fixed. Naming each Map with the Shape Name (spp. name) and text box of spp. name.

Are there ESRI solutions to this, or will this need a Python script?

At first was thinking Data Driven Pages would help; not sure now (looks like that'll do multiple regions of the same layout).

Comment: All of the ~300 layers are in a Group (or Layer File)

Comment: How's your scripting? This sounds like a fairly simple python (arcpy) routine until you get to symbology. Can we have a bit more information about your data please... I take it the layers already have their symbology set or do you have shapefiles with no symbology mixed in? Data driven pages wont do this, it's more for same map multiple extents not so much same extent different maps.

Comment: Unfortunately, my Python skills are primitive (at best). And yes, all ~300 Shapes are symbolized (simple point markers); each reps spp. distributions for a plant (base context map is fixed). Aware that it'd be a  "simple" task of making a list (of the input Shapes), turning each one on, changing a label text box, (now thinking .JPG), turning it off, and looping through list.  But at least I can rest that I'm not missing an aspect of a MapBook like tool that'd facilitate this. Been cranking through and should get to bed sometime tonight!... I appreciate your input.

Comment: I would use ArcPy rather than DDP to do this too.  Starting with all layers turned off, the script would loop through each layer in your layer group to turn it on,  update a pseudo-dynamic text element with the species name (perhaps pulled from the layer name), export the map to PDF and then turn off the layer.

Comment: Yes... thats what I'm thinking... (though my scripting time has suffered greatly since my Avenue and AML days!)... hoping, once things slow down a bit this winter, I can dig into the courses that I have tagged... thnx.

Comment: What else do you want on the map? It wouldn't be too difficult to do it like @PolyGeo indicated if you created the map with all the layers turned off and then turn on, export, turn off. The trick is how to get the species name... as a label. Another alternative would be to merge the points to a single feature class and use a definition query - now *that* you could do with data driven pages, even if you have a map extent polygon duplicated and coincident for all 300 species.

Comment: Well, since I'm showing plant species distributions, I need to include a few base\context features (roads, admin boundaries, a grid system we set up).  And merging the plant points would be very easy (they all share the same data structure).  But I did look at DDP (and have actually produced a few MapBooks) but, as you suggested before, couldn't figure out how to loop through the Spp. Name variable (versus the Place-based grid\strip locator layer) to have the layers turn on off with the map staying stationary..

Comment: All you need is an attribute 'species', numeric would do but the species should also be there in text, to key the extent to the required species, then using a dynamic query on the layer restrict it to just the single species then have dynamic text show the label of the species. You could start with writing a python script to create a Minimum Bounding Feature over the points then attribute and append to the overall extents. It doesn't matter to DDP if the polygons are overlapping so long as one polygons' attributes creates the appropriate query on the merged species layer.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I suspect multiple species records in layers will make for poor display of species names using labels.  I think using [pseudo-dynamic text](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22pseudo-dynamic%22) elements will be a better way to get species names into a title or text box.

Comment: I played around some this afternoon... .including with arcpy.mapping  and found that something is amiss in my python installation (just following the ESRI tutorial, line by line, had the software crashing; refusing to even export a PDF... so, while it's the long (dumb) way... I should have them done tonight... I do intend to catch up, at least with Python, as this is precisely the kind of endeavor that would represent the payoff for the time invested. Thanks again for your points.

Comment: There is what appears to be a code free solution at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58900/non-spatial-data-driven-pages

Comment: I had to go the grunt route and just pound them out... but, once I can catch my breath (after this coming week), I will go through this and see if I can follow it through. Thanks again, sincerely for all the help.